# Able to text and use internet, but no phone calls

Tags: calls, mobile-network, voice-over-lte

It is a refurbished Yureka Note.

I added a newly activated sim in it. It's sending and receiving text messages. After saving the gprs/mms settings sent by mobile operator, I am able to use internet (which is pretty fast) as well.

However, despite trying variety of things, I am unable to make or receive calls on it. When I tried calling it from another number it says: outside network coverage.

Given that signal is full, my guess is that this has something to do with no VoLTE support in this phone.

I tried many options from *#*#4636#*#* also. If I select WCDMA/GSM only then there is no signal. When I use LTE only, there is signal but calling *to* it says Line Busy.

Is there any way to make calling work on this device with this sim?

Comment: You are correct LTE has no own voice service, only VoLTE can be used in a pure LTE environment. If 2G 3G or CDMA Carriers are available and supported by the phone they will be used for phone calls. But those old systems are sometimes already switched off by some mobile network operators.